Is it possible to take the output from ls and make each item a separate variable?
So, for complete transparency I am very new to bash scripting. I have taken on a personal project (to help my team at work) to make a script that backs up the data on our Mac devices and sends it to our remote server. I have a pretty good idea on how to do most of it ( or I'm confident I can find the posting that shows me how to do it). My first idea is to ls the contents of /users and make the output (each individual user profile) a seperate variable. Then prompt the person running the script if they want to back up or delete the profile. Any ideas on how I can approach this? Or is my idea way off? any help is appreciated.
